# Regex expression to match a keyword within a string, delimited by spaces, commas and semicolons

Tags: regex

Imagine I have a very large txt file and that I want to find the word ERP within it.

I want to find the word as a separated point. This means that I don't want for it to be detected as a substring within a word, like for example in the word "PowerPoint".

So I think the best way for this would be to use RegEx with a pattern consisting of ERP, and before and after the word ERP there must be either a space, a comma or a semicolon.
What would be the Regex pattern to find such match?

Furthermore, if the keyword is in the beginning of a TXT line there will be no space, coma or semicolon before word ERP, so this should also be reflected on the Regex pattern (The same if the ERP is in the end of the TXT line?).

Thanks in advance!

---

This last expression is case sensitive. I would like ERP to be detected, but also erp :)

And could you please elaborate or use an example regarding the flag g that you mentioned?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

Comment: Please specify the language or tool you are dealing with.

Comment: Shall 4erp9 match or not match?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do what you asking for

```
\bERP\b
```

When looking for multiple results don't forget the `g` flag. The `g` flag will match all matching results and not just the first one.
If you want to match against erp (small case) add i flag (make the regex case insensitive).
Here is a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/pEsc5E/3) where you can try it against various cases.